# Joomla 3 is giving error after changing hosting company

Tags: php, joomla

I have developed new website in Joomla 3 and now want to transfer it to new hosting and domain.
I have copied all files and directories and created databases. Also changed configuration file.
The problem is that new hosting company runs PHP 5.2.17 version and I removed this string in index.php where it is checking for php version.
After that I have strange error

```
Warning: require_once(__DIR__/includes/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/.../public_html/index.php on line 28

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /usr/.../public_html/index.php on line 28
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance. I can not use php.ini and changing hosting company is big problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum requirement of PHP version is PHP 5.3 for Joomla 3. So you should upgrade your PHP version otherwise use Joomla 2.5

You may get other issues also, if you use Joomla 3 on PHP 5.2. To fix this issue you need to replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 0):

The version check isn't just for show. Requirements for Joomla 3.* is PHP `5.3.1` or higher.

Even if you fix what bugs you find now, you will definitely encounter problems later if you do not upgrade the PHP version.

Just to get an idea of how ugly things can get - check the [PHP changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php). There are a lot of changes in `5.3.0` and `5.3.1`, and any of them can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Nice, I will change my hosting company.